# POST method and arrays

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first php project. I have created a website where users can upload their picture and then view the pictures of other users, one person at a time (similar to the old hotornot.com). The code below works as follows:

1. I create an array (called $allusers) containing all members except for the user who is currently logged in ($user).
2. I create an array (called $usersiviewed) of all members who $user has previously either liked (stored in the likeprofile table) or disliked (stored in the dislikeprofile table). The first column of likeprofile and dislikeprofile has the name of users who did the liking/disliking, second column contains the name of the member they liked/disliked.
3. I use the array_diff to strip out $usersiviewed from $allusers. This is the list of users who $user can view (ie, people they have not already liked or disliked in the past).
   Now the problem is when I click the like button, it updates the likeprofile table with the name of the NEXT person in the array (i.e., not the person who's picture I am currently looking at but person who's picture appears next). Additionally, if I refresh the current page, the person who's profile appears on the current page automatically gets 'liked' by me. I would really appreciate any advice on this.

   ```
   <?php 

   // viewprofiles.php
   include_once("header.php");

   echo $user.' is currently logged in<br><br>';

   echo <<<_END
   <form method="post" action="viewprofiles.php"><pre>
   <input type="submit" name ="choice" value="LIKE" />
   <input type="submit" name ="choice" value="NEXT PROFILE" />
   </pre></form>
   _END;


   $allusers = array();

   //Create the $allusers array, comprised of all users except me
   $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM members");
   $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
   for ($j = 0 ; $j < $num ; ++$j)
   {
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   if ($row[0] == $user) continue;
   $allusers[$j] = $row[0];
   }



   //Create the $i_like_these_users array, comprised of all users i liked
   $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM likeprofile WHERE user='$user'");
   $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
   for ($j = 0 ; $j < $num ; ++$j)
   {
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   $i_like_these_users[$j] = $row[1];
   }

   //Create the $i_dislike_these_users array, comprised of all users i disliked
   $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM dislikeprofile WHERE user='$user'");
   $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
   for ($j = 0 ; $j < $num ; ++$j)
   {
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   $i_dislike_these_users[$j] = $row[1];
   }

   //Create the $usersiviewed array, comprised of all users i have either liked or disliked
   if (is_array($i_like_these_users) && is_array($i_dislike_these_users))
   {
   $usersiviewed = array_merge($i_like_these_users,$i_dislike_these_users);
   }
   elseif(is_array($i_like_these_users))
   {
   $usersiviewed = $i_like_these_users;
   }
   else
   {
   $usersiviewed = $i_dislike_these_users;
   }

   // this removes from the array $allusers (i.e., profiles i can view) all $usersviewed (i.e., all the profiles i have already either liked/disliked)
   if (is_array($usersiviewed))
   {
   $peopleicanview = array_diff($allusers, $usersiviewed);
   $peopleicanview = array_values($peopleicanview); // this re-indexes the array
   }
   else {
   $peopleicanview = $allusers;
   $peopleicanview = array_values($peopleicanview); // this re-indexes the array
   }


   $current_user_profile = $peopleicanview[0];
   echo 'check out '.$current_user_profile.'s picture <br />';
   if (file_exists("$current_user_profile.jpg"))
   {echo "<img src='$current_user_profile.jpg' align='left' />";}

   // if i like or dislike this person, the likeprofile or dislikeprofile table is updated with my name and the name of the person who liked or disliked
   if (isset($_POST['choice']) && $_POST['choice'] == 'LIKE')
   {
   $ilike = $current_user_profile;
   $query = "INSERT INTO likeprofile VALUES" . "('$user', '$ilike')";
   if (!queryMysql($query)) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
   }

   if (isset($_POST['choice']) && $_POST['choice'] == 'NEXT PROFILE')
   {
   $idontlike = $current_user_profile;
   $query = "INSERT INTO dislikeprofile VALUES" . "('$user', '$idontlike')";
   if (!queryMysql($query)) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
   }

   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you refresh page it sends previus value of
Form again...and problem when u like a user it being liked next user.. There there is something in yor for loop while fetching row ...insted of for loop try once while loop ...i hope it will solve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the `$iLike` variable with the currently loaded  user and then updating the database with that user.

You should probably change your application logic a bit:

- pass the user ID of the user you liked or did not like as a POST parameter in addition to the like/didn't like variable
- move the form processing logic to the top of your page (or better yet separate out your form processing from HTML display)

Also, it's best not to use the `mysql_*` extensions in PHP.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO.`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to make two different forms. One with "LIKE", another with "NEXT" to avoid liking from the same form
2. When you submit your form - your page refreshes, so in string `$current_user_profile = $peopleicanview[0];` array `$peopleicanview` doesn't have user from previuos page (before submitting) you have to attach it, e.g. in hidden field

   ```
   <form method="post" action="viewprofiles.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="current_user" value="$current_user_profile" />
   <input type="submit" name ="choice" value="like" />
   </form>
   <form method="post" action="viewprofiles.php">
   <input type="submit" name ="go" value="next" />
   </form>
   ```

   and INSERT it later

   ```
   "INSERT INTO likeprofile VALUES" . "('$user', '".$_POST['current_user']."')"
   ```

   ps remove `<pre>` from your form

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by simplifying and organizing the code.

```
<?php 
 // viewprofiles.php
include_once("header.php");

//if form is sent, process the vote.
//Do this first so that the user voted on wont be in results later(view same user again)
//use the user from hidden form field, see below
$userToVoteOn = isset($_POST['user-to-vote-on']) ? $_POST['user-to-vote-on'] : '';

    // if i like or dislike this person, the likeprofile or dislikeprofile table is updated with my name and the name of the person who liked or disliked
if (isset($_POST['like']))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO likeprofile VALUES" . "('$user', '$userToVoteOn ')";
    if (!queryMysql($query)) 
        echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

if (isset($_POST['dislike']))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO dislikeprofile VALUES" . "('$user', '$userToVoteOn ')";
    if (!queryMysql($query))
        echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

//now we can create array of available users.
$currentProfileUser = array();

//Create the $currentProfileUser array,contains data for next user.
//join the 2 other tables here to save php processing later.
$result = queryMysql("SELECT `user` FROM `members`
                      WHERE `user` NOT IN(SELECT * FROM `likeprofile` WHERE user='$user')
                      AND `user` NOT IN(SELECT * FROM `dislikeprofile` WHERE user='$user')
                      and `user` <> '$user'
                      LIMIT 1");
//no need for a counter or loop, you only need the first result.
if(mysql_num_rows > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $current_user_profile = $row['user'];
}
else
 $current_user_profile = false;



echo $user.' is currently logged in<br><br>';  

//make sure you have a user
if($current_user_profile !== false): ?>
<form method="post" action="viewprofiles.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="user-to-vote-on" value="<?=$current_user_profile?>" />
    <input type="submit" name ="like" value="LIKE" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="viewprofiles.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="user-to-vote-on" value="<?=$current_user_profile?>" />
    <input type="submit" name ="dislike" value="NEXT PROFILE" />
</form>

check out <?=$current_user_profile?>'s picture <br />
    <?php    if (file_exists("$current_user_profile.jpg")): ?>
       <img src='<?=$current_user_profile.jpg?>' align='left' />
    <?php    endif; //end check if image exists ?>
<?php else: //no users found ?>
 Sorry, there are no new users to view
<?php endif; //end check if users exists. ?>
```

You'll notice I changed the code a lot. The order you were checking the vote was the main reason for the issue. But over complicating the code makes it very difficult to see what's happening and why. Make an effort to organize your code in the order you expect them to run rather a vote is cast or not, I also made an effort to separate the markup from the logic. This makes for less of a mess of code to dig through when looking for the bug.

I also used [sub queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) in the original query to avoid a bunch of unnecessary php code. You could easily have used [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) with the same outcome, but I think this is a clearer representation of what's happening. Also please use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) instead of the deprecaded mysql in the future, and be aware of SQL injection attacks and makes use of real_escape_string at the very least.

Hope it works out for you. Also I didn't test this code. Might be a few errors.